# How to properly use equals() if comparing an object array index and an object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, equals

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368385/does-an-array-object-explicitly-contain-the-indexes), roughly, if we had a Classroom object array of student objects, class[index] != student1. I believe this is the mistake I am making in implementing my equals method to compare the array[index] object to another object. I believed the array[index] and the object I am comparing against to be the same.

The code below shows my getNumStudents method in which I try to count the number of times a student id shows up in a class. ID represents brand shoes he or she likes (practice exercise out of lecture). This method is in my classroom object class which implements an interface.

```
@Override
public int getNumStudents(T anEntry) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++) {

       if (roster[index].equals(anEntry)) )
        {
            counter++;
        } 
    } 

    return count;
}
```

My equals method is as such and is implemented in the student class:

```
public boolean equals(Student student) {
    if (this == student)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (student == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getID() != student.getID())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't know if I properly did the hashCode override but here it is (in Student class):

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + studentID;
    return result;
  }
```

I've narrowed down where the bug is to most likely here:

```
   if (roster[index].equals(anEntry)) )
```

specifically

```
roster[index].equals(anEntry))
```

What should I call or how should I adjust my getNumStudents(T anEntry) method to properly return the number of students with a certain ID (representing a shoe type) within a Classroom object array?

Comment: Why dont you just check roster[index].getId() == anEntry.getId() if getId is int.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I didn't post the entire code but its because i'm working with generics in my Classroom class

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab Also, roster[index] and anEntry are two different things according to my IDE. Not the same types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `equals` signature is wrong.

The correct signature of `equals` method must be as follows.

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

Then inside the method you should check if it is of comparable type and if you really need it to be of type `Student`, you have to check for this and return `false` otherwise.

In your case that would be a minimal change required for your implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (this == other)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // This also works if `other` is `null`
    if (!(other instanceof Student))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now we cast it to `Student`
    final Student student = (Student) other;

    if (this.getID() != student.getID())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why is it public boolean equals(Object obj)? I actually ran tests with equals inside my main using two student classes and it responded correctly. Does Object obj basically allow me to handle my array[index] references in the getNumStudents method?

Comment: Wow thanks, it actually works! Can you explain the code below 'we cast it to 'Student'?

Comment: @mobcityzkore Not sure what to explain.  Before this line you have a generic `Object`, so you cannot call `Student` methods on it.  In order for it to act as `Student` you have to cast it.  It is unsafe to cast it before the call to `instanceof` as it can throw `ClassCastException`, and by `equals` contract it MUST accept any kind of object (e.g. `Teacher`), and including `null`, and return `true` or `false` without throwing exceptions